# update a database table field with comma separated list from join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I have two tables named `Districts` and `Schools`. The `Districts` table contains a column named `Schools`.

I need to populate the `Schools` column of the `Districts` table from the corresponding `Schools` table, so that each row in the `Districts` table has a comma separated list of values of school names from the `Schools` table.

How can I do this? Should I use an `UPDATE` query or a stored procedure?

I only got as far as:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c379d/1)

**`Districts Table`**

```
+------------+------+---------+
| DistrictId | Name | Schools |
+------------+------+---------+
|          1 | a    |         |
|          2 | b    |         |
|          3 | c    |         |
|          4 | d    |         |
+------------+------+---------+
```

**`Schools Table`**

```
+----------+------------+------------+
| SchoolId | SchoolName | DistrictId |
+----------+------------+------------+
|        1 | s1         |          1 |
|        2 | s2         |          1 |
|        3 | s3         |          2 |
|        4 | s4         |          2 |
|        5 | s5         |          4 |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

**How the Output Needs to be**

```
+------------+------+---------+
| DistrictId | Name | Schools |
+------------+------+---------+
|          1 | a    | s1,s2   |
|          2 | b    | s3,s4   |
|          3 | c    |         |
|          4 | d    | s5      |
+------------+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help of `FOR XML PATH` and **[STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)** to CONCATENATE the values, you can easily update the table `District` with your desired result.

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.Schools = b.SchoolList
FROM    Districts a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  DistrictId,
                    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + SchoolName
                            FROM Schools
                            WHERE DistrictId = a.DistrictId
                            FOR XML PATH (''))
                        , 1, 1, '')  AS SchoolList
            FROM    Districts AS a
            GROUP   BY DistrictId
        ) b ON A.DistrictId = b.DistrictId
WHERE   b.SchoolList IS NOT NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba798/1)

Comment: Use `STUFF(..., 1, 2, '')` instead since delimiter `', '` is 2 characters - this will prevent the list from having a leading space